# Enable/Disable asp validation control in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I want my validation control to be enable/disable with javascript. When I click on radiobutton list(yes/no), 2-3 rows becomes visible. Once Yes is clicked, then and only then user has to enter input for the textbox provided in that rows. For this I have kept require field validators. I am disabling all of them on page load and again enabling in javascript using ValidatorEnable(control, enable). But in this case, when ever I click on radio button list the rows becomes visible and at the same time validation control shows error message. I want error message to be seen on the submit button click only. Till then no message should appear.
How can I do so..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add code below right after `ValidatorEnable(control, enable)` method call:

```
if (control.style.visibility == "visible") {
     control.style.visibility = "hidden";
} else {
     control.style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function HasPageValidators() {
    var hasValidators = false;

    try {
        if (Page_Validators.length > 0) {
            hasValidators = true;
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
    }

    return hasValidators;
}

function ValidationGroupEnable(validationGroupName, isEnable) {
    if (HasPageValidators()) {
        for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
            if (Page_Validators[i].validationGroup == validationGroupName) {
                ValidatorEnable(Page_Validators[i], isEnable);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then call:

```
ValidationGroupEnable('validationgroup', false);
```

i think it will help you....